# Saved javascript facebook API response remains undefined?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, callback, facebook-javascript-sdk

I suspect it's an issue with asynchronousity, 
I just can't get my head around what's the problem. 
So I make multiple api requests and fill a list with the responses. 
Then I have a D3.js script charting the data, 
which receives undefined though, I substituted it with a simple log here. 
(of course the console "evaluates" the values later in real-time, but logging a nodes[0] item is indeed undefined.)
I tested setting a timeout to the subsequent scripts but no avail, 
and I couldn't come up with a callback solution since the request 
is itself a callback already. 
(I know `forEach` is the proper method to use here, but I'm also trying to get the assignment functional with an immediate return, which is also something I couldn't yet make happen)

```
variables=["pageid1","pageid2","pageid3"];
nodes=[];
variables.map(function(variable){
    FB.api("/"+variable,"GET",{fields:'name,picture.type(large),engagement'},function(response){
        if(!response.error){
            nodes.push(response);
        }
    });
});
console.log(nodes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the requests in a promise. then wait for all the promises to be resolved in which case you will have your nodes variable filled with responses. 
you can do it like so:

```
nodes=[];
function sendRequest( variable ) {
    return new Promise ( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        FB.api("/"+variable,"GET",{fields:'name,picture.type(large),engagement'},function(response){
           if(!response.error)
                 resolve( response );
        });
    });
}

Promise.all( variables.map(function( variable ) {
    return sendRequest( variable ); 
})).then( values => {
     /* All the responses are solved here */
     nodes = values.splice( 0 );
     console.log(  nodes );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Different approach with async/await and some fixes (let, arrow functions, ...):

```
let variables = ['pageid1', 'pageid2', 'pageid3'];
cosnt sendRequest = (variable) => {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        FB.api('/' + variable, {fields:'name,picture.type(large),engagement'}, (response) => {
            if(!response.error) {
                resolve(response);
            } else {
                reject(response.error);
            }
        });
    });
};

const getData = async () => {
    let nodes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
        let response = await sendRequest(variables[i]);
        nodes.push(response);
    }
    console.log(nodes);
};

getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect it's an issue with asynchronousity

Yes, of course, your console.log can and will fire before the `.api` finishes.  Trying to delay it with a `setTimeout` is just bad programming (it's a guessing game).

Any processing on `nodes` needs to be within the `.api` callback.  If you are firing multiple async calls and need them all to finish before processing `nodes` you should be using something like [d3.queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue).  From the docs (bolding mine):

> A queue evaluates zero or more deferred asynchronous tasks with configurable concurrency: you control how many tasks run at the same time. **When all the tasks complete, or an error occurs, the queue passes the results to your await callback**. This library is similar to Async.js’s parallel (when concurrency is infinite), series (when concurrency is 1), and queue, but features a much smaller footprint: as of release 2, d3-queue is about 700 bytes gzipped, compared to 4,300 for Async.

In your case the code might look like this (untested):

```
var q = d3.queue();

variables.forEach(function(d) {
  q.defer(FB.api, "/" + variable, , "GET", {fields: 'name,picture.type(large),engagement' });
});

q.await(function(error, response1, response2, response3) {
  if (error) throw error;
  // build out nodes from responses...
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the cue, I removed `setTimeout` from the sample code for it was hurting my eyes too. D3 is just awesome for having included such a function too. I guess I'll dig in to how it works to understand the solution and maybe get to extract a native one.

Comment: @bpstrngr, added a bit of sample code to get you started (unfortunately, it's untested)